# What application is eoersupzyt.exe a part of?

Tags: windows

I'm looking at a computer where eoersupzyt.exe is consuming significant amounts of bandwidth. What application is this a part of?

Comment: Its part of an infection or malware on your system.

Comment: [See my post here to disinfect your pc](http://superuser.com/a/157533/40928)

Comment: It's not my computer, I have a Mac. Which malware is it part of?

Comment: @stevedbrown Many malwares use random file names. One way to find out is to upload it to https://www.virustotal.com and see what their analysis of the file says.

Comment: I'm sold, now for how to square this on a remote computer.